# ModelForm has no model class specified Error in Django

Tags: python, django, web

**This is my forms.py file!!!**

```
from django import forms
from . models import URLModel

class URLForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = 'URLModel'
        fields = ['url']
```

**This is my models.py file**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class URLModel(models.Model):
    url=models.URLField(unique=True)
    short=models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.url
```

**Now i just wanted to ask that why this error is coming and i have revieved and i cant observe any error for real...please help**

Comment: I also tried removing the " " from "URLModel" in the file forms.py but same error keeps on coming!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
# Remove single quote from your model specification in forms.py

from django import forms
from .models import URLModel

class URLForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = URLModel
        fields = ('url',)
```

Comment: Are you able to import your model, because there is a gap between . and models while importing your model - from .models import URLModel

Comment: Brio it worked it just needed a line space between main and Meta class.